# Update session cookie in Phoenix

Tags: javascript, cookies, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using Phoenix for my web app. 
During login, i save token in cookies like this:

```
conn
    |> put_resp_cookie("user_token", token, max_age: 7*24*60*60) # a week from now
    |> configure_session(renew: true)
    |> redirect(to: "/home")
```

I can see cookie and it's relative max_age in Application > Storage > Cookies (Chrome browser).

On the user profile page, i let them change their password.
Once the password has changed and stored backend side, i generate a new valid token for that password, sending it back to the client as response body. Now i must update "user_token" stored in Application > Storage > Cookies (Chrome browser).
Should i do it backend or frontend side? I tried backend side, before sending the response, like this:

```
    conn
    |> put_resp_cookie("user_token", NEW_TOKEN, max_age: 7*24*60*60) # a week from now
    |> configure_session(renew: true)
```

but it's not working. I have a plug that check the token validity and once a user changes password, any action will redirect him back to login page, because the token is not updated yet. If i check it in the browser control panel it's always the old one

Comment: Are these examples based on the auth system described in "Programming Phoenix" by Chris McCord?

Comment: Dunno, i just implemented it. Everythings works well. i just need to update token in cookie before page reload, otherwise user will be redirected to login page cause of the old invalid token

Comment: The renew option of `configure_session(conn, renew: true)` [generates a new session id for the cookie](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#configure_session/2). I don't think you have to update the user token. In the book it holds the signed current user ID only and the ID of the record should not be changed, so the token should not be changed. The user token is used to authenticate a user while connecting to a channel not within request and response communication.